# Could not set the default value of selection at Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

Recently i start work Angular 6. i find problems while setting the default value for **Select** element. In fact i am looking for object based **Select** element. here is my HTML

**.html file:**

```
<div>
  Select The Country
  <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedCountry3">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [ngValue]="country">{{country.CountryName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  Selected Coutry is : <b>{{SelectedCountry3.CountryName}} -- {{SelectedCountry3.Id}} </b>
</div>
```

**.ts File:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-angular-drop-down',
  templateUrl: './angular-drop-down.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./angular-drop-down.component.css']
})
export class AngularDropDownComponent  {


  countryList: CountryM[];

  SelectedCountry3: CountryM;
  constructor() {

    this.countryList = [
      { Id: 1, CountryName: "Bangladesh" },
      { Id: 2, CountryName: "India" },
      { Id: 3, CountryName: "Pakistan" },
      { Id: 4, CountryName: "Srilanka" },
      { Id: 5, CountryName: "Mayenmar" },
      { Id: 6, CountryName: "Bhutan" },
      { Id: 10, CountryName: "Maldivs" }
    ];

    this.SelectedCountry3 = { Id: 2, CountryName: "India" };

  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return item.Id; // or item.id
  }

  }



interface CountryM {
  Id: number;
  CountryName: string;

}
```

The Problem is when the Select the value from **Select** element i got the Country Object and But i can not set the default value of **Select** through
the Country Object. In AngularJS it works. But in Angular it does not. Do Any one have idea why? or am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compareWith compareWith takes a function which has two arguments: option1 and option2. If compareWith is given, Angular selects option by the return value of the function.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  Select The Country
  <select [(ngModel)]="SelectedCountry3" [compareWith]="compareFn">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countryList" [ngValue]="country"> 
    {{country.CountryName}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>

  Selected Coutry is : <b>{{SelectedCountry3.CountryName}} -- 
 {{SelectedCountry3.Id}} </b>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 compareFn(c1, c2): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 && c1.CountryName === c2.CountryName ;
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8x8hkc

Comment: Thanks i Marked it as answer. But i thing this approach will effect at performance for dowp down list have 100 or more items. i Tested with 5 items. For settings the default value it call CompareWith function 15 times!... so i thing as the items of dropdown increases performance decreses. Is There any dynamamic approches

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because, while those objects have the same values, one does not `===` the other because they are separate instances.

Instead, you can do

```
 this.SelectedCountry3 = this.countryList[1];
```